# Help with a formula for Google Adwords

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am creating a spreadsheet to calculate Adword formulas and I am stuck in how to calculate the **Monthly Net Income** for each keyword. I have created a formula which calculates it but can't figure out how to limit the **Monthly Budget**.

The formula I've created is this one:

> Monthly Net Income = ( DailyClicks x ConversionRate x SaleProfit) - ( CPC x DailyClicks )

There is an example of the formula in the file which is a Google Spreadsheet publicly available here: https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AnQMyM9XJ0EidDB6TUF0OTdaZ2dFb2ZGNmhQeE5lb0E&hl=en_GB#gid=2

*(you can create your own copy going to File > Make a copy...)*

I am releasing this set of tools as Public Domain so feel free to use it :)

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the formula as presented is not calculating the monthly net income, it is calculating the daily net income

assuming 30 days/month, divide the monthly budget by 30 to get a daily budget

then limit the DailyClicks to be no more than DailyBudget / CPC